# Change a block programatically, accesing to the Views results

Tags: views

I have a Views block, which prints a list of products, in unformatted text. I would like to wrap each of these items with a custom href string, which is somehow convoluted and so it is difficult to set in the Views options. I have managed to do so, by retrieving the Views results with **hook_views_pre_render** and

```
foreach($view->result ...
```

and then print the results directly to screen. If I use, instead,

**block_view_VIEWS_MY_VIEW_BLOCK_alter** and

```
$data["content"]["#markup"]
```

I have the problem that the data is in raw form and cannot achieve my initial goal.
What method should I do for this apparently simple goal? I want the block to be finally printed by Drupal, even if modified with the href added programatically, but the rest of properties (pager, etc.) remaining untouched. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reading from some sources and experimenting a little, I have been able to reply to my question. In your template, you must put the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php file (from themes folder), and there you can modify each of the rows based in some logic (though logic should be constrained to template.php y from there populate a variable in this tpl).
The output of the view must be unformatted text, and the "auxiliary" data must be added, but hidden from view.

```
<?php

/**
* @file
* Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
*
* @ingroup views_templates
*/
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
<h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; $i = 0;?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
<?php 

if($view->result[$id]->taxonomy_term_data_description != ""){
 // Here I use a logic to show only the item name surrounded by dots.
  print ".." . $row . "..";
}else{
 // Here I use opposite logic to show the link
     print "<a href='" . $view->result[$id]->taxonomy_term_data_description . "'>" . $row . "</a>";
} // if
$i++;
 ?>
```

Comment: It might be helpful to others if you show how to handle the logic in template.php.

Comment: Well, there are many ways. I think that you could extract the data from database, etc., in template.php, depending on the node->type, etc., and then set **$variables['variable']** with the array, which you would loop. In that case a function like **views_get_view_result** may be helpful. When I finish some example I would return here to show that example.